# What is the reason for using private models in MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry this may be a newbie question but suppose I have a custom object which I want to pass to my view via some action so my code will be

```
Private model db = new model();
Public Actionresult Index()
{
Return View(db);
}
```

But I can also do this

```
Public Actionresult Index()
{
db = new model();
Return View(db);
}
```

Is the method 1 just convention or does it have any reason?

Comment: Well, if `Index()` is called more than once (I'm not sure if it is or not) it will create _new_ instances of your model each time and return different instances. The first method instead creates a single model and shares it each time `Index()` is called.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if the model is used across different actions. This way, you remove the redundancy of creating the model in each method, but it will be created whether the action needs it or not.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Controllers are not re-used. They're always created.

Comment: Good practice states that everything should be as private as possible so you should never expose any object more that it needs to be.

Comment: @Simon exactly. Also if you are working with multiple methods in a single controller I think it is better to initialize it within the action as it would save memory????

Comment: Controller instances are recreated upon every request. Private instance members are NEVER shared between requests then. Both two first comments seem to be wrong on this.

Comment: @FloodGravemind An request in ASP.NET will create a new instance of your controller class every time. No two method will be called within the same instance unless you do it in one of your action. In this case, I'd suggest making that other method private and pass the model as a parameter.

Comment: @Flood,if memory was a concern, the instantiation of the object should be in a using statement anyway , so that it is discarded when it goes out of scope, so I agree with you.

Comment: Anyway, if we really want to be picky, there should be a repository pattern created! The context shouldn't be used in the presentation layer.

Comment: They're both the same. Instantiating a new Model each time an Action is called is excessive and I doubt you'll have a need to create a new Model each time.

Comment: @Everyone It seems we has come a long way since the time of Borland :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in my comment, there's is very little use of the first method. Say you have this controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View(new Model1());
    }

    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return View(new Model1());
    }
}
```

Then, moving the `new Model1()` in a private field will remove the redundancy of creating in every action.

```
public class HomeController
{
    private Model1 model = new Model1();

    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

However, if you introduce this method:

```
public ActionResult Action2()
{
    return View(new Model2());
}
```

The advantage is moot since you will be creating your `Model1` even if the `Action2` doesn't need the model. This is the case because `Controller`s are not re-used in MVC, they're always created.

**Edit:** To expand on that, you need to know what for every request, in Asp.Net, a new instance of your controller is created. This means that, unless one of your actions call another method, no two method will be called in the same instance of a controller. There is no advantage to put the model in a private field. In my example, `Index` and  `Action1` will never be called within the same instance of the `HomeController`. It means that even if you put it in a private field, a new object will be created for the two actions, in two different requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the example, either version will return a reference to the new model.

You could simplify it even further:

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
     Return View(new model());
}
```